# TortoiseGit - how to remove User profile directory as repository?

Tags: svn, tortoise-git

Before I switched to **TortoiseGit**, I used **TortoiseSVN**, which i like.
I could create a folder anywhere, then checkout (clone) repository inside it, then create another folder on other place, and checkout other repo there.

Recently, I switched to TortoiseGit, which i cant understand at this moment... On my desktop, all files & folders are shown as if they were already a clone of something:

[image]

I haven't chosen my desktop to be a repository anywhere  during installation or setting, but seems that my `c:\users\my_user` folder is marked for versioning.

So, how can I remove/unmark that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you opened the context menu on your desktop and selected "Create git repository here...".

TortoiseGit makes the current folder a working tree whereas TortoiseSVN creates a new folder and puts the new repository into that folder. Therefore, create an empty folder first and then create a repository there.

You can fix this by deleting git `.git` directory (might be hidden).

Comment: yes, that was case!

Answer (score 0):

It seemed that I had to delete the `.git` folder from that directory.

Method A) manually delete that hidden folder from windows explorer.

or

Method B) you can use cmd command (just change username):

`rmdir /S /Q "C:\Users\my_user\.git"`

Answer (score 0):

open git bash then execute below command $ rm -rf .git